# browser specific css for internet explorer 7,8,9

Tags: html, css

please do not consider this question as repetative one,as I new bie to the world of CSS,
I am working on a new project , and it had lot of css files, By googling i  come to know about the functionality of css and its usage , I wanted to know one thing let say if I am writing a small css example , I want to write a browser specific css stylesheet specifically for  Internet explorer 7,8 and 9, Please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: use meta condtion for IE7-9 specific css files.

Comment: Sorry, but even as a newbie you could have used a search engine.

Comment: @Sudip Pal could you please post a tag also, that will be helpful a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional comments:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link/><![endif]-->
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

For just one IE version use

```
<!--[if IE 9]><link href="ie9.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><![endif]-->
```

Change the version ("9") to your desire. If you want to address all versions less than or equal to a specific one, use:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link href="ie0-9.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><![endif]-->
```

This will address all versions from 0 to 9, but not 10. For more detailed info please check the link I posted.

Comment: thanks a lot could you post a sample tag also

Comment: @TuntunDffhf seriously? Have you even bothered to look at the link Linus has posted? Everything can be found here > http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/